# How to make a method that returns a trajectory a projectile passes?

Tags: c#, methods, physics

I'm trying to make a method that will receive: initial position of a projectile as `Vector2`, its initial momentum `Vector2`, a formula by which those two should change `?`, a stopping condition `?`, and return a `List<Vector2>`.

**Edit**:

Apparently I wasn't clear enough the first time. What I'm asking for is the explanation of how the method should be written so that it accepts certain arguments along with a method in some form that can be used to calculate a `Vector2` in my case.

Here is a simplified situation with structure similar to my problem:

```
Vector2 Position = new Vector2(0, 0),
        Momentum = new Vector2(1, 1);

void Update()
{
    Position += Momentum;
}

bool CheckStoppingCondition()
{
    if (Position.X >= 10) return true;
    else return false;
}

void NormalExecution()
{
    if (!CheckStoppingCondition()) Update();
}

List<Vector2> CalculateTrajectory (Vector2 pos, Vector2 mom, ???)
{
    List<Vector2> graph = new List<Vector2>();
    ?
    return graph;
}
```

What is CalculateTrajectory method supposed to look like?

---

I'm thinking what I'm looking for might involve delegates.

Comment: Its not clear where you're getting. Is it the method signature for a "formula parameter"

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking a programming question or a physics question?

If a programming question, please be more precise about what you're asking - as it stands, it seems pretty straightforward - just apply the "change formula" in a loop using some time step value until the "stopping condition" is met, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171(v=vs.80).aspx for info on how to pass the "change formulas"/"stop conditions" to your method.

If it's a physics question ("how do I calculate position/momentum after X seconds given initial conditions"), try https://physics.stackexchange.com/ , or see e.g. http://www.xinventions.com/main/spud/motion_equ.htm